# Local truncation error of Adams-Moulton method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

In numerical methods for solving ODEs, the local truncation error of the Adams-Bashforth method can be shown to be $$T(t)=\mathcal{O}(h^{r+1}).$$
I was wondering, what is the local truncation error for the Adams-Moulton (AM) method? I have proved that for AM$2$:
$$T(t)=-\frac{1}{12}y'''(t)h^2+\mathcal{O}(h^3),$$ though I am having trouble generalising this result. Here we define the general formula for the r-step AM method to be $$y_{n+1}=y_n+h\sum_{j=-1}^{r-1}b_jf(t_{n-j},y_{n-j}), \ \ n\geq r\geq 0.$$

Comment: You need to be careful what you use as truncation error. If it is just the defect in the last formula when inserting an exact solution $y(x_i)$ for $y_i$, then indeed you should get $T(t,h)=O(h^{r+1})$. In your last question and apparently in your computations here, you use the more common formula where the defect is divided by $h$, so that the error should be of size $O(h^r)$, where $r$ is the order of the method.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sorry, the term is still new to me. But I do believe it is just the defect in the general formula $y_{n+1}$. Here, I have provided the general formula for the AM method, and I agree that $T(t)=\mathcal{O}(h^r)$. For the AB method with the general formula $$y_{n+1}=y_n+h\sum_{j=0}^r b_j f(t_{n-j},y_{n-j}), \ n\geq r\geq 0,$$ $T(t)=\mathcal{O}(h^{r+1})$. Have I got it right?

Comment: As far as I see, no. Both AB2 and AM2 are second order methods, with 2 $f$ values on the right side. The only difference is a slightly different structure in the error terms and that the coefficients in them are smaller for the implicit method.

Comment: @LutzLehmann So how can express $T(t)$ for the AM method?

Comment: By its construction, the error of the AM method is $O(h^r)$. Your question is somewhat strange, show that a method that is constructed to have order $r$ actually has order $r$. You would need to specify the method you prefer for the construction of the coefficients.